# Login button won't fire

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm using Django and AngularJS in a log in form. In this case, the `username` is in email format. My login form's button will only become un-disabled when the user enters a string formatted like an email address and a password of at least eight characters. But clicking the login button does nothing. Nothing fires. No POST request is made.

`forms.py`:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    '''
    Form to log in a user
    '''
    error_messages= {
        "invalid_login": _("Incorrect %(username)s/password combo")
    }

    title=  "Sign in"

    username=   forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"id":"id_login_username", "type":"email", "placeholder":"Email", "ng-model":"login.email"}))
    password=   forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Password", "ng-model":"login.pw", "ng-minlength":settings.MIN_PW_LENGTH}))
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += [url("^login-register/$", views.login_register, name="login_register"),]
```

`views.py`:

```
def login_register(request, template="pages/login_register.html"):
    registration_form=  RegisterForm()
    return render(request, template, {"registration_form":registration_form})
```

`login_register.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n mezzanine_tags staticfiles %}

{% block meta_title %}{% trans "Register or log in" %}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Register or log in" %}{% endblock %}
{% block extra_head %}
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    {% compress js %}
        <script src="{% static "js/login-register.js" %}"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
  <div id="login-register-wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form id="login-form" name="loginForm" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if login_form.non_field_errors %}
            <p class="text-danger" role="alert">{{ login_form.non_field_errors.as_text|cut:"* "|escape }}</p>
        {% endif %}                 
        {% for field in login_form %}
            <p>{{ field }}</p>
            {% if field.errors %}
                <small class="text-danger" role="alert">{{ field.errors.as_text|cut:"* "|escape }}</small>
            {% endif %}                     
        {% endfor %}
        <button id="login-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="!loginForm.username.$valid || !login.pw">Log in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock main %}
```

`login-register.js`:

```
var app=    angular.module("app",[]);
app.config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("[[[");
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol("]]]");
});

app.controller("Ctrl",function($scope, $rootScope){

});
```

Why does the form not submit when I click the login button after I properly fill out the "Email" and "Password" fields? And why does the button successfully submit when I remove all AngularJS from my files?

Update: And here's what the `form` HTML looks like in the browser.

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" class="ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-valid-email ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-invalid-minlength ng-submitted">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="aHUiUqU1EDmTcqgr5SpyELLnR8dsNh6mTExN7FqmiwX1ykPYlZBcrOBWjRA9YlBj">       <p><input id="id_login_username" name="username" ng-model="login.email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required="" class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-required ng-valid ng-valid-email ng-touched"></p>    
    <p><input id="id_password" name="password" ng-minlength="8" ng-model="login.pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="" class="ng-invalid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-invalid-minlength ng-touched"></p>                   
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form data won't go anywhere unless you tell it where to go. Your form does not submit because it lacks an action or ng-submit.

The action attribute is a form handler that you put on the form element, e.g.

```
<form id="login-form" name="loginForm" method="post" action="/your-endpoint">
```

But the angular way is to specify an ng-submit function.

```
<form id="login-form" name="loginForm" method="post" ng-submit="foo()">


$scope.foo = function() {
 // ...
 // do whatever extra logic you need to, then
 //   $http.post('./your-endpoint', formdata)
}
```